# How to get branch name from JSON?

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [
        {
            "date": "xyz",
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
                "branch": [
                    {
                        "SHA1": "5213affe970c86cd6e13b9d0e52515ac53f46aae",
                        "name": "feature/demo"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "abc",
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
                "branch": [
                    {
                        "SHA1": "ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100",
                        "name": "refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "kkk",
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
                "branch": [
                    {
                        "SHA1": "433d2ec97cdd1ca01c352aa0b8510e0a8f93fa0c",
                        "name": "refs/remotes/abcd/feature/demo_abcd"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON Object is too long for Jenkins multibranch pipeline so I have shred a few limited objects from JSON.

Using the above JSON object how to get the only `name` and `sha1` from JSON for specific `name`?

I need results like the below:

```
refs/remotes/abcd/feature/demo_abcd:433d2ec97cdd1ca01c352aa0b8510e0a8f93fa0c
```

Comment: Where is the "below code" you have used?

Comment: the indentation of the JSON is a bit misleading. `"branch"` should be indented more than `"lastBuiltRevision"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the approaches:

```
data = {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [
        {
            "date": "xyz", 
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
            "branch": [
                {
                    "SHA1": "5213affe970c86cd6e13b9d0e52515ac53f46aae", 
                    "name": "feature/demo"
                }
            ]
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "abc", 
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
            "branch": [
                {
                    "SHA1": "ca7972a32cc28304c22c98ceabf8e349fbf1a100", 
                    "name": "refs/remotes/xyz/feature/demo_xyz"
                }
            ]
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "kkk", 
            "lastBuiltRevision": {
            "branch": [
                {
                    "SHA1": "433d2ec97cdd1ca01c352aa0b8510e0a8f93fa0c", 
                    "name": "refs/remotes/abcd/feature/demo_abcd"
                }
            ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
branch_name = "refs/remotes/abcd/feature/demo_abcd"
for actions in data['actions']:
    for branch_data in actions.get('lastBuiltRevision', {}).get('branch', {}):
        if branch_data.get('name') == branch_name:
            print (f"NAME: {branch_data['name']}, SHA1: {branch_data['SHA1']}")
```

Output:

```
NAME: refs/remotes/abcd/feature/demo_abcd, SHA1: 433d2ec97cdd1ca01c352aa0b8510e0a8f93fa0c
```